# THREE.JS ShaderMaterial exceeds of my mesh

Tags: three.js, shader

I have a classic mesh composed by a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` and a material. If I add a `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()` here's the result I get :

[image]

So far, so good. But when I call my `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`, using an external texture, the dimension of my mesh completely changes :

[image]

I always get that weird ratio even if - like in the screenshot - my texture is a square (512x512). I just want my MaterialShader to fit inside my geometry.

Here is the code of my MaterialShader :

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
   uniforms: uniforms,
   vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
   fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
} );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

I don't see what I'm missing. Does anyone has an idea ? Thank you very much.

UPDATE :
Here's the fully code of my ShaderMaterial :

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms:{
        u_time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
        u_resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        u_mouse: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
        texture1: { type: "t", value: texture }
    },
    vertexShader:`
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    `,
    fragmentShader:`
        #ifdef GL_ES
            precision highp float;
            precision highp int;
        #endif

        uniform vec2 u_resolution;
        uniform vec2 u_mouse;
        uniform float u_time;

        uniform sampler2D texture1;

        void main(){

            float pyt=3.1415926*2./3.;
            float m=-1e10;
            vec4 mv= vec4(0.);

            vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

            int ic=0;

            for (int i=0;i<30;i++){
                vec2 np=vec2(xy.x+float(i)/u_resolution.x*sin(3.14/2.)  * 4.,xy.y+float(i)/u_resolution.y*cos(3.14/2.) * 4.);


                float jTime = u_time*1.618;  
                vec4 tk=texture2D(texture1,np);
                float t=tk.r*sin(jTime)+tk.g*sin(jTime+pyt)+tk.b*sin(jTime+2.*pyt)-.01*float(i);

                if (t>m){m=t; mv=tk;ic=i;}
            }
            float sc=float(ic)/30.;
            vec4 tk=texture2D(texture1,xy);
            mv=sc*tk+(1.-sc)*mv;
            gl_FragColor = vec4(mv.r,mv.g,mv.b,1.0);
        }
    `
});
```

UPDATE2 : 
I changed my vertex shader but nothing has changed.

I might have a lead : I think this is related to my camera settings. I changed them and I've a better result. Now my texture fits into my square mesh.

Unfortunately, the scale isn't good. Since my texture is a square too, I want it to have exactly the same size than my mesh, for now it's zoomed.

How can I manage the size of my texture ? Should I do it inside my vertexShader ?

Here's my texture settings for now :

```
texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "test5.jpg");
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

UPDATE 3 :

I found that code to apply a texture and make it fit to my mesh :
https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/c8375f1c313587ac629e04e0253481f9

It's working but as soon as I change the example fragement shader by mine, I've no errors but the shaders become one unique color. I don't understand what I'm missing...

Comment: Could you provide the object of `uniforms` and the code of shaders?

Comment: Sure, just added it @prisoner849 !

Comment: @prisoner849 I'm still looking for a way to make my square texture fit perfectly to my square mesh, I added several updates to my main post but I still can't manage to do it...

Comment: Just out curiousity, why do you use such a complicated fragment shader for such a simple task like mapping a texture to a plane? I've updated the answer. A square texture to a square plane.

Comment: @prisoner849, thank you for your answer and your time ! I'm using a fragment shader because I want my texture to get distord in addition to perfectly fit into my square (here the fragment I want to use : https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xt2yzc you can see the result in my screenshot upper). I successfully made the bridge between the vertex shader and the fragment shader using `varying vec2 vUv`. Unfortunately my issue remains because the two times my `texture2D(texture1,xy)` function is called, it doesn't use `vUv` as second parameter.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: And I am very grateful ! Thanks you very very much, this works like a charm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code of the vertex shader:

```
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

[Reference](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/)

Simply pass the uv coordinates from the vertex shader to the fragment shader and use them there.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var iResolution = new THREE.Vector2();

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 5);
var planeMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    texture: {
      value: null
    },
    iResolution: {
      value: iResolution
    },
    iTime: {
      value: 0
    }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                    modelViewMatrix *
                    vec4(position,1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    uniform float iTime;
    uniform vec2 iResolution;
    
    varying vec2 vUv;
    
    void main() {
      float pyt=3.1415926*2./3.;
      float m=-1e10;//very negitive start value for maximisation algorithm.
      vec4 mv= vec4(0.);//lank starting value of max so far

      vec2 xy = vUv;
      int ic=0;//stores smear distance
      for (int i=0;i<30;i++){
          //point offset on a circle
          vec2 np=vec2(xy.x+float(i)/iResolution.x*sin(iTime),xy.y+float(i)/iResolution.y*cos(iTime));
          //colour cycles faster than position
          float jTime = iTime*1.618;  
          //get neerby point
        vec4 tk=texture2D(texture,np);
          // and if its colourfull enough, use that
          float t=tk.r*sin(jTime)+tk.g*sin(jTime+pyt)+tk.b*sin(jTime+2.*pyt)-.01*float(i);
          if (t>m){m=t; mv=tk;ic=i;}
      }
      //mix smeared with background depending ondistance
      float sc=float(ic)/30.;
      vec4 tk=texture2D(texture,xy);
      mv=sc*tk+(1.-sc)*mv;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mv.rgb,1.0);
    }
  `
});

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg", tex => {
  planeMat.uniforms.texture.value = tex;
  planeMat.uniforms.texture.value.needsUpdate = true;
  iResolution.set(tex.image.width, tex.image.height);
  planeMat.needsUpdate = true;
  console.log(texture);
});

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
scene.add(plane);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  planeMat.uniforms.iTime.value = time;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
```